# get all week day from sun to sat of specific week

Tags: php

I have a week format from input week
like so

$the_week = 2020-W01

how can I get all of the weekdays from sun to Sat of this specific week in PHP?
edit

```html
 $first_date =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime("W".$the_week)); //first date
 $d_1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($first_date)));
 $d_2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+2 day", strtotime($first_date)));
 $d_3 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+3 day", strtotime($first_date)));
 $d_4 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+4 day", strtotime($first_date)));
 $d_5 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+5 day", strtotime($first_date)));
 $d_6 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+6 day", strtotime($first_date)));
```

i get 1999

Comment: i have edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [`DateTime` API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php), get the given date then add up to 6 days using [`DateTime#add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and a proper [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$baseDay = new \DateTimeImmutable($the_week . ' -1day');

for ($dayIncrement = 0; $dayIncrement < 7; $dayIncrement++) {
  $day = $baseDay->add(new \DateInterval("P{$dayIncrement}D"));
  echo $day->format('d/m/Y'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/sq5XK**

Comment: how can i get the dates starts from sunday?

Comment: @drorshalit You should be able to get that by substracting a day using `$the_week . '-1day'` as your date format (see my edited answer). Since the first week of the year is the one with a Thursday in it, I believe it should be the same week no matter which of Monday or Sunday is the start of the week (unless I'm mistaken), in which case you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: A leading space is still missing in the string ' -1day'

Comment: @jspit Right! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine

```
<?php
$first_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("W2020-W01"));
$d_1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($first_date)));
$d_2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+2 day", strtotime($first_date)));
$d_3 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+3 day", strtotime($first_date)));
$d_4 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+4 day", strtotime($first_date)));
$d_5 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+5 day", strtotime($first_date)));
$d_6 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+6 day", strtotime($first_date)));
echo $d_1;
echo $d_2;
echo $d_3;
echo $d_4;
echo $d_5;
echo $d_6;
?>
```

What is the issue?

Comment: i  all wase get 1999 or 1998;